# CSS: blue border in IE and Firefox only?

Tags: css

I don't understand why I have this blue border around the links images in my page.

I've set outline:none border:0 but still it is there (only in Firefox and IE)... it is very strange.

http://www.alimdardesign.com/fabulicious/features.html

Thanks

Comment: Update: this issue doesn't occur on IE11+

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Because you have an image inside a link, this border comes up, try this css:

```
a img
{
  border:none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've missed. Can you edit your answer so I can dismiss down vote and set upvote?

Answer (score 2):

every linked image has a blue border around it. do fix this web designers generally use the following css

```
a img
{
  border : 0;
}
```

also try :

```
img
{
  border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is standart behaviour of images inside the a-tags

```
<img border="0" />
```

or

```
a img {
  border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The border style should apply to the image, not the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
a img
{
  border : 0;
}
```

This worked for me. I inserted this exactly into my style.css file and I no longer see the border around the image in IE (no issue with Chrome).

Steve